# load_dataset() from the Huggingface datasets library does not work with Python 3.9, but with Python 3.10 (KeyError())

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.9, python-3.10, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

The minimal working example to load the [Huggingface SQuAD v2](https://huggingface.co/datasets/squad_v2) dataset using

```
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset_squad_v2 = load_dataset("squad_v2")
```

does not work on my Ubuntu 22 machine with **Python 3.9** due to a KeyError(). It does work, however, with **Python 3.10**.

```
lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/features/features.py in generate_from_dict(obj)
   1282 
   1283     if class_type == Sequence:
-> 1284         return Sequence(feature=generate_from_dict(obj["feature"]), length=obj["length"])
   1285 
   1286     field_names = {f.name for f in fields(class_type)}

KeyError: 'length'
```

Is there a way to remedy this issue so that one can use Python 3.9? I noticed similar issues with other Huggingface datasets when using Python 3.9

I've tried to force-download the dataset (instead of re-using the local file) and updated the `datasets` library.

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve this issue? I tried using py_version='py31' instead of py_version='py38' but got an error that supported version is only py38